# Error when set schedule for private video using Google APIs Explorer

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Question:** Why did I get this error? The error message is not informative/helpful. Please assist to solve.

I tried to simulate this on Google APIs Explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.update

Part: status

```
{
 "id": "3zZ1lCz-rp4",
 "status": {
  "privacyStatus": "private",
  "publishAt": "2019-04-12T12:12:12.12Z"
 }
}
```

But not working. Getting response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "invalidVideoMetadata",
    "message": "The request metadata is invalid.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "body"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request metadata is invalid."
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? please edit question and ask clearly.

Comment: Why did I get this error? The error message is not informative/helpful.